Create a custom scaffold option in visual studio
We are building microservices for our application.  We define the table entities using entity framework, then we make an interface, a service, and a controller for each entity that look exactly the same except for the class name (we have a base service and base controller that handle almost everything).  But there's a ton of copy pasting going on to setup the three files for each table.  I want to make a custom scaffolding option that just does all that for us.  But all the information I find online about making a custom scaffold is for Visual Studio 2013.  As far as I can tell there isn't an option for newer Visual Studio versions.  Are there any nuget packages that allow you to extend your scaffolding options or maybe I am just missing a built in option to add a new scaffold in visual studios?

Creating custom scaffolding to achieve all your goals is going to be a bit difficult. If you want to automatically generate the code you want in ASP.NET, I recommend you use dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator.
The following link is the relevant discussion:
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1075
How to use dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-8.0#controller-options
Note:
Take generating Controller as an example. If you want to generate the Controller you want, you need to modify the template. The template is located in C:\Users{Username}.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc{Here you need to find which one your project uses}\Templates\ControllerGenerator.
